# How to store a value obtained from a vector `pop_back()` in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, vector, casting

I'm not sure how to cast a value obtained from the `pop_back()` function of `vector`. The following is a simple code to illustrate the problem.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> a,b;
  int val;

  a.push_back(1);
  a.push_back(2);
  a.push_back(3);
  a.push_back(4);

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    val = a.pop_back();
    b.push_back(val);
  }

  vector<int>::iterator v = b.begin();
  while( v != b.end())
  {
    cout << *v << " ";
    v++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This is the error I get.

```
pushback.cpp:18:9: error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'
    val = a.pop_back();
        ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried casting as well; `(int)a.pop_back()`, but it throws an error stating `C-style cast from 'void' to 'int' is not allowed`.

May I know if there is a standard way to store the value from the `pop_back()` function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It may sound as pop as in returning a value. But it actually doesn't. The standard says that `vector::pop_back` should erase the last value, with no return value.

You can do:

```
auto val = a.back();
a.pop_back();
```

Comment: auto val = a.back(); Does it copy the value? So there is one extra operation.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) `std::vector::pop_back()` does not return any value, you just need to call `std::vector::back()` right before:

```
val = a.back();
a.pop_back();
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the clarification. I just got confused between the different languages (Python, Java, etc.) on how `pop` was implemented. It never crossed my mind that it was a misnomer in C++.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac there is a reason for that, for example what to do if copy or move ctor throws exception?

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a `vector` of objects and not just primitive types, moving out from the vector can be done with `std::move`:

```
auto val = std::move(a.back()); // allow call of move ctor if available
a.pop_back();
```

Note that wrapping the call to `back()` with `std::move` is done only because we know that we are about to erase this element from the vector on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/pop_back/

The pop_back is void function, it is nonvalue-returning.

Answer (score 0):

Or Use the .at(i) operator to return the value. For example

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   val = a.at(i); 
   b.push_back(val);
}
```